# Istio 0.8.0 requires istio-proxy?

Tags: istio

I was wondering if `istio 0.8.0` requires `istio-proxy` to be deployed? I see that there is some `istio-proxy` image pulled in the pod description after sidecar injection.

Comment: What did you investigate?

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to deploy `istio-proxy` itself.
The `istio-proxy` (based on Envoy) is a container within other deployments of istio components and also injected (either manually or automatically) as a sidecar to your own app deployments.
So it makes sense you are seeing this image being pulled from the doocker hub.